# how to filter a fil with regular expression using sed command?

Tags: shell, unix, sed

Can anyone please tell me what these two commands do?

```
sed -i 's!{[^{]*\;}! !' file.txt

sed -i 's!{[^{]*{! !' file.txt
```

---

I found this example and i can not figure out the result provided when running the code.

Comment: this is not a suitable question here.. see 1)https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking 2) https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html 3) https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sed/info

Comment: The second removes the first pair of left braces it finds in each line, along with whatever is between them, and replaces all that with a space. The first is a little more difficult to describe exactly, but it involves a semicolon. What's confusing about the result you see?

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i 's!{[^{]*\;}! !' file.txt
```

- sed -i means in place, file.txt might be altered.
- 's!....!....!' substitute command, splittet by exclamation marks. Most often you will see slashes used, but sed accepts different characters, defined by the first one, following the s. Note that exclamation marks make problems in the shell. Since there is no slash, neither in pattern, nor in replacement, I don't see a reason to use them.
- {[^{]*\;} pattern to match
- ' ' substitution eventually a blank, if transferred with care, but might be a tab or funky half spaces or something else too.

Now what is the complicated expression:

- {[^{]*\;} a literal pair of curly braces containing ...
- [^{]  a negation group, negation is by first char being a '^', so anything which is not a opening, curly brace, followed by
- the quantifier *, meaning in any number, including 0, followed by
- backspace, which is a masking tool, as so often.
- and a semicolon.

So

- '{aaaaa;}' should match
- '{a;}' should match
- '{;}' should match
- '{};}' should match
- '{{;}' should not match
- '{a}' should not match
- '{a}' should not match